memory state container service Blazor WebAssembly
I am trying to implement memory state container service in my Blazor WebAssembly project. I have 2 components (they are not coupled together as parent and child) my main component is responsible for collecting information. Attached code fragment:
@inject ServiceScopped
@inject IDiposable
<EditForm OnSubmit="@HandleSubmit">
information collection
</EditForm>
@Code
{
  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
   {
    ServiceScopped.Change += StateHasChanged;
   }

  private async Task HandleSubmit()
  {
    await Save();
    return;
  }

  private async Task Save()
  {
   var ServiceDTO = new ServiceScoppedDTO 
    {
     // I assign the properties entered in the form
    }
    ServiceScopped.UpdateData(ServiceDTO );
  
    /* I call to open the blank window and generate the table */
    await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("open", "newwindows", "_blank");
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
   ServiceScopped.Change -= StateHasChanged;
  }

}

My main component stores the data but when I open the component in another tab the service appears empty:
@inject ServiceScopped
@inject IDiposable

// Here I print my data in an htm table

@Code{
    private DataDTO ServiceDTO;
  
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
      ServiceScopped.Change += StateHasChanged;
      ServiceDTO = ServiceScopped.Data;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
      ServiceScopped.Change -= StateHasChanged;
    }
}

Program:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ServiceScopped>();

Service:
    public class ServiceScopped
{
    public DataDTO Data { get; private set; } = new DataDTO();

    public event Action? Change;

    public void UpdateData(DataDTO newData)
    {
        Data = newData;
        NotifyStateChanged();
    }

    private void NotifyStateChanged() => Change?.Invoke();
}

My main component sets the data but the secondary component does not receive it, it starts empty.

Hi @Hale Bopp, how do you set the value for ServiceScopped.Data? Did you mean you cannot get the ServiceScopped value in your shared first razor component? It is better for you to share more code design.

Hi @Rena, that's right, from the second component I want to access the data and I do it with ServiceScopped.Data in the OnInitializedAsync() method. The parent component updates the data fine but the child component does not get it.

Hi @Hale Bopp, so how do you set the value for ServiceScopped.Data?

Hi @Rena, I use the UpdateData method of my ServiceScopped service in my main component, when saving the form the OnSubmit="@HandleSubmit" event is started, which contains the Save method and this is the one that saves the data.
"ServiceScopped.UpdateData(ServiceDTO );"
